# Use a Printer and a Scanner on same USB Hub

Tags: 11.10

Can't print and scan from the same USB Hub.. When i try to print it give me a error msg asking if i connected the printer..

When i check for my self if it is connected it is with command lsusb

```
jeff@StudioPC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0040:073d  
Bus 001 Device 118: ID 03f0:2b17 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 1020
Bus 001 Device 039: ID 03f0:3f11 Hewlett-Packard PSC-1315/PSC-1317
```

When i try to add a new printer the LasterJet printer wont show up.. Only the scanner
So how do i configure so the printer will work?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you install the "hplip" and "hpijs" packages using synaptic. These are very important to assist the user with installation and monitoring of the HP printers and scanners and all-in-ones too.

```
sudo apt-get install hplip
sudo apt-get install hpijs
```